# Play pause background audio on click and load events

Tags: plugins, javascript

I am newbie JS and Wordpress user/developer.
I want to play an audio in background when a page loads. Also, would like to pause the same audio if I click few set of buttons. 
I tried using plugins (obviously being a noob), however I can get a sound bar, and a play pause button. But, cannot connect set of buttons to the action. 
How to do I achieve this for events like `on load` or `on click`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pause button:

```
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>
```

Audio:

```
<audio controls>
     <source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
     <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>
```

JS Script:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio"); 

function pauseAudio() { 
    audio.pause(); 
} 

audio.play();
```

I think the code is all pretty straight forward.  Basically, you get the video element, and just run `.play()` on it.  Add to a button's onclick `pauseAudio()` which will run the function and pause the video.

Hope that helps!

Or...

```
  <button onclick="document.getElementById("audio").pause();" type="button">Pause Audio</button>
```

and on the `<body>` tag:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById("audio").play();">
```

Something similar to that should get you going!

This works for videos or audio, I've update this to be more for audio, though the premise is the same.